# How do I run a geospatial query in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database

In the docs, it says that by default, Mongo treats it as lat/long:

> By default, the index assumes you are
>   indexing latitude/longitude and is
>   thus configured for a [-180..180]
>   value range.

So, let's say I have this in my document:

```
post['loc'] = [ -40.234, 56.222]
db.mycollection.save(post)
```

I ensure my index:

```
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({"loc":"2d"})
```

Now, how do I execute the following in Mongo?

- Give me all documents that are within 5 miles of a certain lat/long
- Give me all documents within 400 meters of a certain lat/long

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$near` in conjuction with `$maxDistance`:

```
db.mycollection.find({loc: {$near: [50, 50], $maxDistance: 5}})
```

The unit of `$maxDistance` is the same as the `loc` field, i.e. degrees. A degree is approximately 69 miles or 111 km at the equator, if I remember correctly (but it is less at other latitudes, the exact distance is hard to calculate).

To get more information about the returned locations, you can use the `geoNear` command, which will tell you the distance of all returned collections, among other things. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-geoNearCommand

I think you can also use `$geoWithin` to solve your problem:

```
db.mycollection.find({loc: {$geoWithin: {$center: [[50, 50], 5/3959]}}})
```

This should find all locations within the circle centered at (50, 50) with a radius of 5/3959 degrees (i.e. 5 miles).